# Efficient design of generator for SQLite3 executemany() insert on several tables

Tags: python, database, performance, sqlite

I am parsing a bunch of large xml files into a sqlite3 database in python.  As best I can tell, (although I am very open to and seeking more performant options) the more performant option is sqlite3's `executemany()` function for inserts.

The gist of what I am doing at the moment is as follows:

```
document_dir = '/documents'

Document = named_tuple('Document', 'doc_id doc_title doc_mentioned_people ... etc')
People = named_tuple('People', 'doc_id first_name last_name ... ') 

class DocumentXML(object):
    """
    ... there's some stuff here, but you get the idea

    """

    def parse_document(path):
        """
        This object keeps track of the current 'document' type element from a cElementTree.iterparse() elsewhere

        I've simplified things here, but you can get the idea that this is providing a named tuple for a generator
        """
        doc_id = _current_element.findall(xpath = '../id')[0].text
        doc_title = _current_element.findall(xpath = '../title')[0].text

        # parse lists of people here

        doc_mentioned_people = People(first_name, last_name, ..., person_id)
        #etc...
        return Document(doc_id, doc_title, doc_mentioned_people, ..., etc)

def doc_generator():
    documents = parse_document(document_dir)
    for doc in documents:
        yield doc.id, doc.title, ..., doc.date



# Import into Table 1
with cursor(True) as c:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO Document VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", doc_generator())



def people_generator():
    documents = parse_document(document_dir)
    for doc in documents:
        people = doc.people
        yield people.firstname, people.lastname ..., people.eyecolor


# Import into Table 2
with cursor(True) as c:
        c.executemany("INSERT INTO Document VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", people_generator())


# This goes on for several tables...
```

As you can see, there is a terrible level of inefficiency here.  Each xml file is parsed, over and over again, with the same number of parses as there are tables in the database.

I would like to utilize just one parse of the XML (as I can yield all of the relevant information in one named tuple), but keep the structure as a generator, so as to not blow up memory requirements to unfeasible levels.

Is there a good way to do this?

My attempts have been revolving around using executemany with a double insert type of statement such as:

```
c.executemany("
    INSERT INTO Document VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    INSERT INTO People VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); 
    INSERT INTO Companies VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); 
    INSERT INTO Oils VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?); 
    INSERT INTO Physics VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
        complete_data_generator())
```

Where `complete_data_generator()` yields all of the relevant structured information; However, I know this is likely not to work.

**Is there a better way to structure this for performance?**

Answer (score 0):

If you had few of small documents, you would load everything in memory and will no longer be bothered by re-parsing documents.

If you had one single table to feed, the generator approach would be fine.

If no of those 2 ways are appropriate, I would try a mid-level approach:

- parse the bunch of XML files and accumulate a number of `doc` elements
- when you have a *reasonable* number of documents available, you pause parsing, and start feeding the database tables using *executemany* on that number of docs
- after inserting that *bag* of documents, you optionaly commit to free the SQLite journaling files, and resume parsing

Pros:

- files are only parsed once
- load on the SQLite database can be controlled with intermediary commits
- you still use `executemany`

Cons:

- many calls to `executemany`, depending of the volume of data
- each commit will take some time